# Magento 2.4.3 - Anyone that has experience with Porto theme?

Tags: products, layered-navigation, magento2.4.3

Is there anyone that has some experience with the Porto theme and can give me a hint on how I can get a 3rd party layered navigation to work properly with Porto Theme? I can see they have added Mageplaza's layered navigation to the theme.

What happens is that when you use layered navigation the product photo is breaking the grid.

Comment: You are lucky, your layered navigation is working with porto theme, But I recently bought porto theme with  Mageplaza's layered navigation but it breaks my website so for a while I have disabled this module will work on bug.

Comment: It does work in a way, but breaks my CSS for my product grid.